# Close current window and open a new window when click a href in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Here is my javascript code

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  function logoutClose()
  {
    window.close();
  }
</script>
```

when I click the following `href`, I want the current window to be closed and logout window should be opened. But the problem is sometimes it's working fine, sometimes the current window doesn't get closed but logout window will be opened in a new tab

```
<a href="logout.jsp" target="_blank" onclick="logoutClose()">logout</a>
```

Comment: The language attribute has been deprecated for a decade or more (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) so you might also want to check with a more recent source for your code.

Comment: "language" attribute is not a big issue in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not working sometimes because it closes your main window before browser processes your click.

Try warping into [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function logoutClose() {  
    setTimeout( function () { window.close(); }, 500);
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,it works fine now but my question is why some times its not working fine